# Webpack adds "auto/" to script tags in the built html file

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, electron

So, I'm trying to get this application setup so I can start coding it. But everytime I build the application; webpack automatically adds `auto/file.js` to the script tags, but it should really be: `file.js`. So it's adding the `auto/` part by itself. I've checked every webpack config file, and I cannot understand why it adds the `auto/` prefix to my scripts.

Also like to mention this is a ElectronJS project.
Here are my configurations for webpack.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const mainConfig = require("./webpack.main.config");
const rendererConfig = require("./webpack.renderer.config");
const config = [mainConfig, rendererConfig];
module.exports = config;
```

**webpack.base.config.js**

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      test: /\.js($|\?)/i,
      sourceMap: true,
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: true
      }
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

**webpack.main.config.js**
const path = require("path");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");

```
const base = require("./webpack.base.config");
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist");

const main = merge(base, {
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: buildPath
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      },
    ]
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
  target: "electron-main"
});

module.exports = main;
```

**webpack.renderer.config.js** *(this is where i think the problem is happening)*

```
const path = require("path");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const base = require("./webpack.base.config");
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist");

const renderer = merge(base, {
  entry: "./src/renderer.js",
  output: {
    filename: "renderer.js",
    path: buildPath
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    })
  ],
  target: "electron-renderer",
});

module.exports = renderer;
```

And after the build, when I open the index.html file from the dist directory, the script tag is like this: `<script src="auto/renderer.js"></script>` when it should just be `<script src="renderer.js"></script>`

What could be causing this? Is there any configuration I am missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be related to this issue? https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1514

Comment: Looks like it. Thanks, will follow the github issues page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by updating webpack.